# Reading content from text file c sharp

Tags: c#

I have written a small program to read line from a text but facing a problem when getting the output. As I just get the following:

```
     System.String[]
     System.String[]
     System.String[]
```

instead of having the content of my text file. Here is the written loop:

```
 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Engineer\Desktop\MyFile.txt");
     foreach(string line in lines)
   {
      console.WriteLine("\t"+ lines);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration of the loop, you're writing the array of lines to the output.

```
                            ▼
console.WriteLine("\t"+ lines);
```

Remove the 's'.

Comment: that definitely should have been comment  + close vote ("This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error")

Comment: yes that is so true i completely missed that. Thanks Amy

Comment: @ASh go ahead and vote to close, i agree.  However, I wanted to give him an answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use line instead of lineS:

```
console.WriteLine("\t"+ line);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing "lines" not "line."
Make the variables names more descriptive to avoid the error: lineArray and lineCur.